# Unity, modify standard shader to randomly flip texture?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Imagine a scene with ten simple "cubes" all the same.

They each have the same material "M1" which has the simple standard shader, and, a simple PNG as the texture.

If you go to the material, and adjust the tiling,

[image]

[image]

You can conveniently flip the texture around for different looks.

Note that of course this will change **all ten** of the cubes all at once.

Is it possible to modify the standard shader, so that, simply,

- on each object, which uses the material
- the shader randomly changes the tiling (and, say, the offset)
- again, I mean on a **"per object" basis**; in the example **each** of the ten would be randomly different.

(So: one cube would show tiling -1,1, one cube would show tiling -1,-1 and so on ... each cube different, although all using the **same** material, only one material exists.)

Note,

(1) it's totally trivial to generate a few different versions of the material, each with different tiling, and randomly select one of those for each cube. that's not the way to go

(2) note that if you vary a material, it of course makes more than one copy. you can't have thousands and thousands of materials.

**The solution is to have (one) shader which knows to vary (say, randomly) the offset, inside the shader - on each object it is working on.**  (ie on a per specific object basis)

That's what I'm asking about here.

Comment: Modifying material properties at runtime will create new instance of the same material. Is it ok for your case?

Comment: Right, that is totally not the idea.  (Note italics paragraph.)  I want the shader itself to randomly adjust the offset!

Comment: Sorry in advance for dumb question ) The point here is to generate different looks at runtime from one material, or to have one material instance at runtime for performance (or some other) reasons?

Comment: You're correct.  You'd do this by setting the shader values on the material instance.

Comment: Hi @Immersive - well no man, you would need ***one material for each object*** to do that.  What is wanted is a custom shader that randomly varies the offset, within the shader itself, per object.

Comment: @Fattie, well, yes and no. You'd need a script on each object that modifies the material instanced on the object at run time.  You shouldn't have to modify the materials via inspector.

Comment: To answer your shader question, yes it's doable.  Fairly trivial even, but you have no control over it per object unless you expose a variable, at which point you're back to the current situation of setting uniforms via the material.

Comment: I gave this problem some more thoughts. Correct me if I'm wrong: one material means same shader(s). You cann't generate random value for tiling on every shader pass, so it should be some "global" variable. So anyway we will end up with a few instances of the same shader which means a few instances of material. Also i'm not sure if shader can "differ" objects. On the other hand there are only four combinations of -1 and 1, so at this point assigning four different materials randomly sounds not so bad. But I hope that someone will solve this issue using one material.

Comment: Check this : 
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html

GPU Instancing only renders identical Meshes with each draw call, but each instance can have different parameters (for example, color or scale) to add variation and reduce the appearance of repetition.

Comment: hi @obywan - "You cann't generate random value for tiling on every shader pass"  hmm - wait - can't you have a shader that simply chooses a random solid color (I mean, on each different object)

Comment: Yes, you can generate a random number within the shader... every time it's run (so every frame of every object).

Comment: Yes, @Immersive is right, I meant you can, but you don't want to do that. This way tiling will change every frame.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I noticed that you really really want to do this with nothing but a shader. You can't do this with a shader alone. The issue is not being able to generate a random number in a shader. *The problem is being able to do it once*. I haven't found a way to do so and don't think you can.

This is a problem that should be tackled with a code on the C# side.

> (1) it's totally trivial to generate a few different versions of the
>   material, each with different tiling, and randomly select one of those
>   for each cube. that's not the way to go
>
> (2) note that if you vary a material, it of course makes more than one
>   copy. you can't have thousands and thousands of materials.

Not a problem at-all. This is what [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html) is used for. It allows you to modify a shader property without creating new instance of that material.

> *"Use it in situations where you want to draw multiple objects with the same material, but slightly different properties."* [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html)

The code below would have cause many instances of the material to be created:

```
void Start()
{
    MeshRenderer meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    int tileX = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3) == 1) ? 1 : -1;
    int tileY = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3) == 1) ? 1 : -1;
    Vector2 tile = new Vector2(tileX, tileY);
    meshRenderer.material.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", tile);
}
```

With [`MaterialPropertyBlock`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MaterialPropertyBlock.html), this issue is solved. Material copy is not  made. Since you care about performance, you should also use `Shader.PropertyToID`:

```
void Start()
{
    int propertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("_MainTex_ST");
    meshRenderer = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    int tileX = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3) == 1) ? 1 : -1;
    int tileY = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3) == 1) ? 1 : -1;
    Vector2 tile = new Vector2(tileX, tileY);

    MaterialPropertyBlock matPropBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
    //Get the current MaterialPropertyBlock settings
    meshRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(matPropBlock);
    //Assign the new tile value
    matPropBlock.SetVector(propertyID, tile);
    //matPropBlock.SetVector(Shader.PropertyToID("_MainTex_ST"), tile);
    //Apply the modified MaterialPropertyBlock back to the renderer
    meshRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(matPropBlock);
}
```

If this is done once in the game, it doesn't really make sense to attach the script to each GameObject. Just attach it t to one empty GameObject only, find all the objects by tag then run the code on each one.

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject[] objs = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("YourObjTag");
    int propertyID = Shader.PropertyToID("_MainTex_ST");
    for (int i = 0; i < objs.Length; i++)
    {
        MeshRenderer meshRenderer = objs[i].GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        int tileX = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3) == 1) ? 1 : -1;
        int tileY = (UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 3) == 1) ? 1 : -1;
        Vector2 tile = new Vector2(tileX, tileY);

        MaterialPropertyBlock matPropBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
        //Get the current MaterialPropertyBlock settings
        meshRenderer.GetPropertyBlock(matPropBlock);
        //Assign the new tile value
        matPropBlock.SetVector(propertyID, tile);
        //Apply the modified MaterialPropertyBlock back to the renderer
        meshRenderer.SetPropertyBlock(matPropBlock);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying ... CafeUCafe's answer is very nice, but, in fact you still have to push in the random value, from the Object.  Cool.  MaterialPropertyBlock, news to me  :)

Comment: Yes, you still have to use C# to push the value. Not only that, CafeUCafe's answer accesses the `mesh` property which also causes new instance to be created. `sharedMesh` propety  can be used to solve that but then it will change the original object and they will all look the-same. `MaterialPropertyBlock` makes sens here

Comment: Yup. It creates new MeshFilter for each mesh.

Comment: Really this is the **correct and full answer** to this QA.  Good one.  Awesome information.  "gameDevelopmentGerm" 's answer is so tricky he deserves the bounty, particularly as a new user!   :)

Comment: @Fattie I like his answer even though it has moving restriction but he did put some work on that.

Comment: it's ingenious right?  a new user deserves a bounty :)  this answer os yours is fantastic and will help a lot of folks adopt this new critical technology.  Good one.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Pseudorandomly flipped]

```
Shader "RandomFlip"
{
Properties
{
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
}
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" "DisableBatching"="True" }
    LOD 100

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag
        #pragma multi_compile_fog

        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            // position of pivot in world space
            float3 pivotWorldPos = float3( unity_ObjectToWorld[0].w, unity_ObjectToWorld[1].w, unity_ObjectToWorld[2].w );

            // randomness achieved by feeding trigonometry function with large numbers
            float flipHorizontally = sin( ( pivotWorldPos.x + pivotWorldPos.y + pivotWorldPos.z ) * 1000 ) > 0;
            float flipVertically = cos( ( pivotWorldPos.x + pivotWorldPos.y + pivotWorldPos.z ) * 1000 ) > 0;

            // randomly flipping uvs 
            float2 uv = lerp( v.uv, float2( 1.0 - v.uv.x, v.uv.y ), flipVertically );
            uv = lerp( uv, float2( uv.x, 1.0 - uv.y ), flipHorizontally ); 

            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(uv, _MainTex);
            UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {
            // sample the texture
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
            // apply fog
            UNITY_APPLY_FOG(i.fogCoord, col);
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
}
```

Though you better not moving these objects :D Because randomness here are coming from position of object in world space. Batching will also break the randomness.

Comment: this answer from the enigmatic new user IS SO CLEVER it deserves the bounty !!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to flip use alpha = 0 for those objects, and for others alpha = 1.

In vertex data of your shader write something like this:

half flip = 1 -2*vertex.a;

So the flip would be -1 or 1.

From the comments:

[image]

**Note however that each time you access `.mesh` , in Unity, you are making a whole new mesh:**

```
public class TestFlipUV : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private void Awake()
        {

            Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
            // NOTE. IN UNITY, ACCESSING .mesh CREATES
            // A NEW INSTANCE OF THAT MESH EVERY TIME

            Vector2[] uv2 = mesh.uv;

            float rnd = Random.RandomRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
            if (rnd > 0.5f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < uv2.Length; i++)
                {
                    uv2[i].x *= -1;    
                }
            }

            rnd = Random.RandomRange(0.0f, 1.0f);
            if (rnd > 0.5f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < uv2.Length; i++)
                {
                    uv2[i].y *= -1;    
                }
            }
            mesh.uv2 = uv2;
        }
    }
```

... and then ...

```
Shader "Unlit/FlipUV"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
        LOD 100

        Pass
        {
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;
            float4 _MainTex_TexelSize;

            v2f vert (appdata v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.uv = v.uv;
                o.uv *= v.uv2;
                return o;
            }

            fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, i.uv);
                return col;
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Note that OP never mentioned anything about alpha.

Comment: Oh, i see, i thought he was using sprites, but it does not matter. He can use this trick to modify the vertices or some params in uv.zw of mesh to grab this value in vertex shader and pass to fragment. So no need to change materials, just pass some data to mesh.

Comment: Please read the question again to understand what OP is actually shooting for. He wants to change the tiling offset value (See screenshot in the question). That's it.

Comment: Yeah, i see it. So i assume that he wants to change _MainTex_ST.xy, he wants to flip the tile not from inspector (because it will change it for  every object) but from shader. So he just need multiply my flip var to uv.x. uv.x *= flip - it would be uv.x*=1 (not flip) or uv.x *=-1 (flip is here) so its identical like you changing in inspector tilling field. Or i am missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. The flipping for both axis should be random.

Comment: Oh, my mistake. Then he could try something like mesh.uv2 = new Vecto2(Random(-1,1),Random(-1,1)) - and declare float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD1 in shader; And multiply uv *= uv2; So **uv2** is set to flip one of axis of **uv**

Comment: Edit it to your answer. Make sure to test that in Unity and verify that it works before posting it.I say this because I think that wouldn't work.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/kp2czl - yes it works, idea is right.

https://pastebin.com/Fh9LRPjD - code
https://pastebin.com/mXwfjYiB - shader

Comment: hi @CafeUCafe - **it seems that almost works**, I would urge you to edit your answer, you are allowed to put in all the code in your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I will post this as answer, you can try it and see if it works for you. (If not, maybe someone else will find this solution helpful). Tiling can be changed with `SetTextureScale`

Attach for each cube.

```
public class MatTilingChange : MonoBehaviour {
    MeshRenderer mr;
    int[] vals = new int[] { -1, 1 };

    private void Awake()
    {
        mr = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    }

    void Start () {
        mr.material.SetTextureScale("_MainTex", new Vector2(vals[Random.Range(0, 2)], 
vals[Random.Range(0, 2)]));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is totally wrong, sorry man.  (1) as I very clearly said, the whole point of the question is to NOT do it this way  :)  (2) **AND DO PLEASE NOTE** - as a rule you generally CAN NOT do this in Unity. If you have 1000 objects, *you will be generating 1000 materials which stick around for ever* - you will crash even your watercooled gaming machine!   :)

Comment: (It's rather like accidentally Find'ing an object every frame, you know?)

Comment: Yeah, it would generate a material for each affected object. That's why I wanted to know if there is performance concern in your question.